# Receive window notifications

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an `NSWindow` set up in Interface Builder. I have set the class of `File's Owner` to my `NSWindowController` and linked the `window` property of the controller to my `NSWindow`.
My controller implements `NSWindowDelegate`.

Now, in my controller, I have added the following:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    [self.window setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)windowDidBecomeMain:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Did become main.");
}
```

Still, `-windowDidBecomeMain:` isn't called. Does anyone know why this is?

**EDIT**:

Trying to show a window from `AppDelegate` on launch. The main nib (declared in `Info.plist`) contains a menu item only which is linked to the `AppDelegate`. In the application delegate, I show an icon on the status bar and when this icon is clicked, I display the menu from the main nib.
In the application delegate, I also want to display a window which should have a window controller assigned to take care of the logic.
I believe that when this works, I will receive my window notifications.

Now, the following code doesn't show the window and I can't figure out why.

```
DemoWindowController *dwc = [[DemoWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DemoWindowController"];
[dwc showWindow:self];
```

Note that `self` is the application delegate.

Comment: Is you window controller actually the object that opens the window? If it isn't then your files owner will not be getting set correctly.

Comment: I'm very new to Mac OS development but have been doing iOS development for a couple of years. Honestly, I have a hard time figuring out the role of the window controllers and the role of the application delegate. It does not seem to be the same for iOS and Mac OS. I instantiate the window controller from the `AppDelegate`. Is this why I don't receive the notifications and can you tell me what I should do different, then?

Comment: Is your application a document based application or not?

Comment: No, it's not. I don't use the `NSDocument` class at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is due to the fact that your window controller is not actually the object that is the nibs file owner.

When you change the class in interface builder you are telling it what outlets and actions are available (which is why you are able to drag to the window outlet) but you are still responsible for passing in this object yourself.

In the case of a non-document based application, you will have a main method which calls `NSApplicationMain`. What this does is basically look up and load the window nib that is specified in your info.plist file and pass the current `NSApplication` instance to this nib as the files owner (so even though you changed the class type to `NSWindowController`, the object being passed in is actually of type NSApplication).

The easiest way to fix your problem is to get rid of your window controller for now (as it isn't actually doing anything yet).

You should implement the `-windowDidBecomeMain:` method in your app delegate. Then Ctrl+drag from your window to your appDelegate to set it as the delegate of the window to get your notifications.

**Update**

To answer your question regarding the `WindowController` beware of the following two issues:

1. You are creating your window controller variable (dwc) in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method. This is released the moment you leave the method taking your window with it. Create an instance variable to hold onto the window controller instead.
2. Ensure that your second window nib has its file owner set to NSWindowController (or your window controller type) and that its window outlet is connected to the window in the nib file.

Your window should now display.

Comment: I think you have lead me on the right course. I want to display a window from my `AppDelegate` so that this window is display on launch. My main nib (declared in `Info.plist`) contains a menu item only. I have created a new nib file and want to add a window controller to take care of the logic for this window. In my ` AppDelegate` I try to show a new window (see my original question) but the window does not show up. Do you have an idea why this is happening? I believe that when the window is shown, it will have my window controller assigned and I will receive the window notifications.

Comment: Have you told your `WindowController` which nib file to load? the common way to do this is to call `– initWithWindowNibName:` passing in the name of your nib file.

Comment: Yes, I did pass the name of the nib. In my original question I show how I have initialized the window controller and how I try to display the window.

Comment: In `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

Comment: try calling `[YourWindowController window];`.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: I created a new project and then I could successfully show a new window. I don't know what I did wrong but I will try to look into that. Anyways, now I can successfully retrieve notifications when the window becomes main. Thank you for your help!